# SQL-Query - finding pattern of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison

I have a table with colors:

```
COLORS

idColor   Name
-------   ------
   4      Yellow
   5      Green
   6      Red
```

And I have another table with data:

```
PRODUCTS

idProduct   idCategory   idColor
---------   ----------   -------
    1           1           4     
    2           1           5     
    3           1           6     
    4           2           10    
    5           2           11    
    6           2           12    
    7           3           4     
    8           3           5     
    9           3           8     
    10          4           4     
    11          4           5     
    12          4           6     
    13          5           4     
    14          6           4     
    15          6           5
```

I just want return rows from `Products` when the `idColor` values from table `Colors` (4, 5, 6) are present in the second table and `IdCategory` has exactly 3 elements with the same `idColor` values `4, 5, 6`.

For this example, The query should return:

```
IdCategory
----------
    1      
    4
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server, please?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT idCategory
FROM PRODUCTS
GROUP BY idCategory
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN idColor IN (4,5,6) THEN idColor END) = 3
```

[Here is a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b727c/2) for you to try.

**UPDATED**

If you want to dynamically filter the results depending on the values of the table `COLOR

```
SELECT idCategory
FROM PRODUCTS P
LEFT JOIN (SELECT idColor, COUNT(*) OVER() TotalColors
           FROM COLORS) C
     ON P.idColor = C.idColor
GROUP BY idCategory
HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(C.TotalColors)
AND COUNT(DISTINCT C.idColor) = MIN(C.TotalColors)
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/607fe/2) with this example.

Comment: +1 I like this syntax.  Less verbose than my answer when dynamically generating the `IN` list -- don't have to provide it twice.

Comment: @EliGassert Your answer also works fine, so +1 to you too for giving different choices to OP

Comment: But you've hardcoded the values `4, 5, 6`... how can this be what the OP wants when the data is in a table and could change the next time he wants to run the query?

Comment: @ErikE I didn't actually thought that the values of the table `COLORS` were only `(4,5,6)` in his example, I saw that table as a table with all the colors available. Now I don't really know it the values need to be hardcoded or retrieve from the `COLORS` table

Comment: @ErikE maybe yes, maybe not. We'll need op to clarify his question

Comment: Data in Table COLORS could change, it could be idColors: {3,4,5 and 6} and then, idCategory would change finding 4 elements with the same idColors, what happen in this case? Can I test: "...AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN idColor IN (4,5,6) THEN idColor END) = 3" for another way: "...AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN idColor IN (*SELECT ID'S WHERE**) THEN idColor END) = @COUNTER_IDS" ???

Comment: So @GermanLeal then please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15100082/57611), which allows for the data in the table to change.

Comment: @Lamak One more thing I just noticed is that you only need the `DISTINCT` if colors can be duplicated inside a category.

Comment: @GermanLeal @ErikE updated my answer so it dynamically filter the results depending on the values of the `COLORS` table.

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregates to make sure it has all 3 colors, and also to make sure it **DOESN'T** have any other colors.   Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT idCategory
  , SUM(CASE WHEN idColor IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GoodColors
  , SUM(CASE WHEN idColor NOT IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BadColors
FROM Products
GROUP BY idCategory
) t0
WHERE GoodColors = 3 AND BadColors = 0
```

Note, if the 4, 5, 6 is found more than once per idCategory then a different technique must be employed.  But from your example, it doesn't appear that way.

Comment: But you've hardcoded the values `4, 5, 6`... how can this be what the OP wants when the data is in a table and could change the next time he wants to run the query?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you would like to perform this task based on data in a table, rather than hardcoding the values 4, 5, and 6 (like in some of the answers given). To that end, in [my solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1abf4/2) I created a `dbo.ColorSets` table that you can fill with as many different sets of colors as you want, then run the query and see all the product Categories that match those color Sets. The reason I didn't just use your `dbo.Color` table is that it appeared to be the lookup table, complete with color names, so it didn't seem like the right one to be picking out a *particular set* of colors rather than the entire list possible.

I used a technique that will maintain good performance even on huge amounts of data, as compared to other query methods that use aggregates exclusively. No matter what method one uses, this task will pretty much always require a scan of the entire `Products` table because you can't compare all the rows without, well, comparing all the rows. But the JOIN is on indexable columns and is only for the candidates that have a very good chance of being proper matches, so the amount of work required is greatly reduced.

Here's what the `ColorSets` table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ColorSets (
   idSet int NOT NULL,
   idColor int NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT PK_ColorSet PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (idSet, idColor)
);

INSERT dbo.ColorSets
VALUES
   (1, 4), 
   (1, 5),
   (1, 6), -- your color set: yellow, green, and red
   (2, 4),
   (2, 5),
   (2, 8)  -- an additional color set: yellow, green, and purple
;
```

And the query ([see this working in a SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1abf4/2)):

```
WITH Sets AS (
   SELECT
      idSet,
      Grp = Checksum_Agg(idColor)
   FROM
      dbo.ColorSets
   GROUP BY
      idSet
), Categories AS (
   SELECT
      idCategory,
      Grp = Checksum_Agg(idColor)
   FROM
      dbo.Products
   GROUP BY
      idCategory
)
SELECT
   S.idSet,
   C.idCategory
FROM
   Sets S
   INNER JOIN Categories C
      ON S.Grp = C.Grp
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM
         (
            SELECT *
            FROM dbo.ColorSets CS
            WHERE CS.idSet = S.idSet
         ) CS
         FULL JOIN (
            SELECT *
            FROM dbo.Products P
            WHERE P.idCategory = C.idCategory
         ) P
            ON CS.idColor = P.idColor 
      WHERE
          CS.idColor IS NULL
          OR P.idColor IS NULL
   )
;
```

Result:

```
idSet  idCategory
 1       1
 2       3
 1       4
```

Answer (score -3):

If I understand your question, this should do it

```
select distinct idCategory
  from Products 
 where idColors in (4,5,6)
```

Comment: This returns 3, 5 and 6 as well.